# How to structure data for R?

Tags: r, dataframe

So... newbie R user here.  I have some observations that I'd like to record using R and be able to add to later.

The items are sorted by weights, and the number at each weight recorded.  So far what I have looks like this:

```
weights <- c(rep(171.5, times=1), rep(171.6, times=2), rep(171.7, times=4), rep(171.8, times=18), rep(171.9, times=39), rep(172.0, times=36), rep(172.1, times=34), rep(172.2, times=25))
```

There will be a total of 500 items being observed.

I'm going to be taking additional observations over time to (hopefully) see how the distribution of weights changes with use/wear.  I'd like to be able plots showing either stacked histograms or boxplots.

What would be the best way to format / store this data to facilitate this kind of use case?  A matrix, dataframe, something else?

Comment: If you are planning on investigating how your data set changes over time, you would probably benefit from using a `data.frame` (or better yet, a `data.table`), so that you can include non-`numeric` columns like the date / time new samples are added, etc... that are of potential use to you.

Comment: I've heard of `data.frame`s before... but not `data.table`.  I did a little digging and found a description on CRAN.  I'm not planning on making *that* many rounds of observations - maybe 10-20.  Certainly not (I hope!) gigabytes worth.  Would the advantage still be worth it?

Comment: Well that depends - it's true that `data.table`s have a huge performance advantage over `data.frame`s in many regards, and this is sometimes the primary reason for using them. However, there are also syntactic differences between the two classes which may persuade you to use one over the other. If you are very new to R, `data.frame`s might seem more straightforward to work with, because their syntax more closely resembles the rest of base R language structure. However, I personally find that `data.table`s are generally more convenient to work with because of features like the native ...

Comment: ... ability to calculate grouped statistics (`Dt[,list(Mean=mean(x),Median=median(x)),by=list(y,z)]`); adding / modifying columns with `:=`, which is a convenience benefit as well as a performance benefit, since the object is modified by reference rather than by value; referring to columns without quoting their names; etc... If you plan on using R in the long run, you will almost surely get turned on to `data.table`s at some point, so it might make sense for you to get acquainted with them sooner rather than later. If not, they are definitely worth looking into down the road.

Comment: Most plotting and analysis functions will want their data to be in "long" form, so arrange as dataframe with  Value in one column and Obs_period in another.

Comment: @memilanuk re: you comment to my answer, you need to have the `weights` vector, as in your question already defined. I mentioned this in the first line after the Toy Example header. You would also need to `install.packages("ggplot2")` then load it with `library(ggplot2)` if you don't have that installed already.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments have suggest, the most versatile (and perhaps useful) container (structure) for your data would be a data frame - for use with the `library(ggplot2)` for your future plotting and graphing needs(such as [BoxPlot with ggplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html) and various [histograms](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)

### Toy example

All the code below does is use your `weights` vector above, to create a data frame with some dummy IDs and plot a box and whisker plot, and results in the below plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
IDs<-sample(LETTERS[1:5],length(weights),TRUE) #dummy ID values

df<-data.frame(ID=IDs,Weights=weights) #make data frame with your 
#original `weights` vector
ggplot(data=df,aes(factor(ID),Weights))+geom_boxplot() #box-plot
```

[image: bw plot]

Comment: I know its just a 'toy' example, but it didn't seem to work on my system.  Not sure about the IDs... not really running anything that requires factors at this point.  All I'd envisioned was an array or 'table' of values, one batch per column, ~500 entries in each column.  The observations (weights) wouldn't be tied to anything but the date they were taken.

Comment: In that case, you could see this question and use of `geom_plot` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584637/how-to-add-legend-in-a-ggplot2-bar-chart/25585049#25585049. Data frames (and data tables) are useful for processing data and "viewing" data in different ways. I can appear complicated at first, but is often the most versatile (read future proof) way to collect and preserve your data. That has been my experience, anyway. Good luck